# throw exception on file extension

Tags: php, exception, throw

how i can do a throw exception of this type?

if i have a file with extension.xlsx ok, if my file extension is another throw new exception error etc

thank you for support

i have to do this control here

```
function getexceldata($excelfilepath){
    $excelfilepath='/home/b2bmomo/test/esempio.xlsx';
    if (!is_readable($excelfilepath))
            {
                throw new Exception('File ('.$excelfilepath.') not readable');
            }
    try {
```

after the exception filepath is readable i have to do this

Comment: First of all, you should place all code fragments where you want to throw exception, in `try` block. So you should check file extension in `try` block and if extension is not allowed throw new exception

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
function getexceldata($excelfilepath){
    $excelfilepath='/home/b2bmomo/test/esempio.xlsx';
    if (!is_readable($excelfilepath))
    {
            throw new Exception('File ('.$excelfilepath.') not readable');
    }
    ( ... )
}

try
{
    $result = getexceldata( $excelfilepath );
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Otherwise, if you are looking for this way:

```
function getexceldata($excelfilepath){
    $excelfilepath='/home/b2bmomo/test/esempio.xlsx';
    try
    {
        if (!is_readable($excelfilepath))
        {
            throw new Exception('File ('.$excelfilepath.') not readable');
        }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

please note that it makes little sense. Use this syntax instead:

```
function getexceldata($excelfilepath){
    $excelfilepath='/home/b2bmomo/test/esempio.xlsx';
    if (!is_readable($excelfilepath))
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```